# Minecraft Modding: "Cannot Get Property" Error when procedurally registering blocks

Tags: java, minecraft-fabric

I am currently developing a Fabric Mod that adds "cracked", "mossy", and similar variants to nearly every block in the vanilla game. Obviously, I am not going to manually register roughly 800 new blocks for every variant I'd like to add to the game, and I've opted to procedurally register all of the variants in a loop. My current strategy involves looping through all of the blocks in the vanilla game and registering a block with the variant name plus the block name. ("Cracked Oak Planks", "Cracked Amethyst Block", etc.) That works completely fine, and I'm also able to generate model files for every block that has the same face on all six sides. (Generating "cracked" variants of blocks that have different textures on different faces is something I haven't even begun to tackle, but that's a problem for the future. It shouldn't be too complicated... probably?)

I began running into issues when I tried to register new blocks that inherit the properties from their parent block. The properties I'm trying to inherit shouldn't be crazy complicated, I'm not currently planning on adding blocks such as a "mossy sticky piston" or a "cracked light blue bed" - I don't care about variants of functional blocks. I'm just trying to have a block inherit properties such as hardness and material.

```
public static void registerModBlocks() {
        for (Field block : Blocks.class.getFields()) {
             Block blockObject = (Block) block.get(null);

             TutorialMod.LOGGER.info(block.getName());

             Block settings = new Block(FabricBlockSettings.copyOf(blockObject));

             String blockName = "cracked_" + block.getName().toLowerCase();
             gen_blocks.put(blockName, registerBlock(blockName, settings, ModItemGroup.ITEM_GROUP));


        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code I'm using to accomplish this goal. I'm referencing the class that each block name refers to and creating a copy of their settings. This works totally fine when it comes to basic blocks such as planks or cobblestone but throws an error when trying to register logs or redstone ore.

This is the error code for logs:

`Cannot get property EnumProperty{name=axis, clazz=class net.minecraft.util.math.Direction$Axis, values=[x, y, z]} as it does not exist in Block{minecraft:air}`

This is the error code for redstone ore:

`Cannot get property BooleanProperty{name=lit, clazz=class java.lang.Boolean, values=[true, false]} as it does not exist in Block{minecraft:air}`

I understand why this error is being thrown, the "axis" property of logs is specific to whatever class extends the "Block" class to add special behavior to logs. The same thing goes for redstone ore, that property comes from a class that extends "Block". It makes sense that those properties can't be applied to a template in which that property doesn't exist.

Does anybody have ideas as to how I should go about getting around this? Ideally, I could create a conditional that detects what type of Block is being parsed and create a different settings object based on that, but I have no clue where to even begin doing that. Another solution I've considered is creating tags that denote what type of setting a block should use when being created, but I'd like to avoid that. I want this system to be flexible - if a new type of log is added to the game, I don't want to have to update a json file.

I'm not really sure what the solution is, but I'd love to get some advice! I'm pretty new to Minecraft modding and I wouldn't be surprised if there's a really easy solution I've overlooked. I couldn't find any answers to this question online, but I'd love to be linked to resources if you know about them! Thanks to anyone that's able to help!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at using Open Worthwhile Operations (owo-lib), it contains utilities that mimic what you are trying to achieve:

https://docs.wispforest.io/owo/registration/

Dynamically registering items depending on the fields of a class is a more complex problem than you might think.

*Also, when creating StackOverflow posts, try make it short and to the point!*